# Como filtrar um data frame?

Tags: r, data.frame

Tenho um data frame com 5597 linhas e 7 colunas. Gostaria de filtrar os resultados desse data frame, de forma que só apareçam as linhas em que a segunda coluna está escrito "AC". Tentei usar o comando `dr=subset(df, df[2]=="AC")`, onde `df` é meu próprio data frame e 2 é a coluna onde aparece "AC". Infelizmente, o comando não funcionou. Há algo que possa fazer para melhorar o código?

Comment: A principio seu código está ok. Qual o erro que você recebe? Coloque também uma amostra dos seus dados.

Answer (score 6):

Bom, a princípio o seu código está correto, ele deveria fazer o subset dos dados, o que pode ter ocorrido é algum outro problema que somente seria possível verificar com o caso específico.

Mostrando em um data frame de exemplo:

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(valor= rnorm(100), categoria = rep(c("AB", "AC"), 50), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dr <- subset(df, df[2]=="AC")
```

Veja que `dr` tem apenas as linhas cuja segunda coluna é "AC":

```r
unique(dr[2])
  categoria
2        AC

head(dr)
        valor categoria
2   0.1836433        AC
4   1.5952808        AC
6  -0.8204684        AC
8   0.7383247        AC
10 -0.3053884        AC
12  0.3898432        AC
```

Há diversas outras formas de filtrar um data frame. Uma delas seria usar o operador `[` do R. Exemplo:

```r
dr <- df[df[2]=="AC", ]
```

ou

```r
dr <- df[df$categoria=="AC", ]
```

Há também pacotes específicos para manipulação de dados. Um pacote excelente para isso é o [`dplyr`,](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) pois é bastante rápido e tem uma sintaxe intuitiva (por exemplo, o comando para filtrar chama-se "filter").

No `dplyr` ficaria assim:

```r
library(dplyr)
dr <- df%>%filter(categoria=="AC")
```

Se você vai trabalhar muito com bases de dados, vale a pena dar uma olhada.

Comment: testei e funcionou!

Comment: Muito bom Carlos Cinelli.. Carlos o pacote não seria plyr

Comment: @LucasCosta não plyr é outro pacote, esse é dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

Disponibilizo também um exemplo a partir do pacote `data.table` utilizando os dados do exemplo de @Carlos Cinelli.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(valor = rnorm(100),
                 categoria = rep(c("AB", "AC"), 50), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df <- data.table::data.table(df)
df <- df[categoria == "AC"]
```