# Realizar um filtro e salvar em csv

Tags: r, data.frame, csv

Gostaria de realizar um filtro no R. Tenho um banco de dados com 5 variáveis e mais de 5000 linhas. Uma das minhas variáveis é "sala", na qual eu possuo 29 sala (ex:sala1,sala2...).

Eu gostaria de realizar um filtro, para filtrar todas as informações que contém no meu banco de dados referentes a uma determinada sala, e depois exportar essas informações em um arquivo csv.

Cheguei a fazer um programa, porém não esta armazenando direito em um arquivo csv. Gostaria que alguém me desse uma dica para melhor meu código e/ou me ajudar a resolver esse problema do armazenamento. Abaixo segue meu código.

```
dados=read.csv("C:/teste/dados.csv", sep=";",header=TRUE) 
nome=dados$nome
perfil=dados$perfil
sala=dados$sala
forum=dados$forum
mensagem=dados$mensagem
BD=data.frame(nome,perfil,sala,forum,mensagem)
x2=subset(nome,sala=="(T2/14/EI) D01 - Diversidade e Cultura Inclusiva")
x3=subset(perfil,sala=="(T2/14/EI) D01 - Diversidade e Cultura Inclusiva")
x6=subset(sala,sala=="(T2/14/EI) D01 - Diversidade e Cultura Inclusiva")
x7=subset(forum,sala=="(T2/14/EI) D01 - Diversidade e Cultura Inclusiva")
x10=subset(mensagem,sala=="(T2/14/EI) D01 - Diversidade e Cultura Inclusiva")
dados1=paste(x2,x3,x6,x7,x10,sep=";")
cat("nome;perfil;sala;forum;mensagem", dados1, file="arquivo.csv", sep="\n",header=T)
```

Comment: Qual o comportamente actual do código?

Comment: Então JJoao ele está até realizando a filtragem corretamente, porém quando peço para armazenar em um arquivo csv, está armazendo tudo "bagunçado".

Comment: Qual código você está utilizando para gerar o .csv? Seu data.frame quando você escreve o .csv, está correto? Recomendo utilizar o comando: write.csv(seuDataFrame, file = "seusDados.csv") para gerar o .csv a partir de um dataframe

Comment: Estou usando isso: dados1=paste(x2,x3,x6,x7,x10,sep=";")
cat("nome;perfil;sala;forum;mensagem", dados1, file="arquivo.csv", sep="\n",header=T). Eu não conhecia essa comando, vou tentar usar

Comment: Vale a pena você dar uma olhada nessa questão também sobre formas de filtrar um data.frame: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17439/como-filtrar-um-data-frame/17479#17479

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para salvar no formado *CSV* brasileiro da para usar o `write.csv2()` (e para ler, `read.csv2()`). Além do mais, tu pode usar o `subset()` em um data.frame, simplifica bastante o teu código:

```
dados <- read.csv2("C:/teste/dados.csv", header=TRUE)
write.csv2(subset(dados, sala == "(T2/14/EI) D01 - Diversidade e Cultura Inclusiva"), "arquivo.csv",  row.names = FALSE)
```

O parâmetro `row.names = FALSE` serve para tirar a coluna com o número da linha (eu pessoalmente acho que ela só atrapalha)

Comment: Muito obrigada, muito obrigada mesmo! Ajudou muito a minha vida.